# Different Karate Report using Gradle

Tags: karate

Am using Karate with Gradle.
The concern i have is that with gradle am only getting the default Junit report which does not gives a clear count picture as glimse and not that neat to read.

Can you help me with any other report which i can use for Karate with gradle? Maybe cucumber or some other report please

Answer (score 0):

This should be your best reference: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Gradle

And refer the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report - to get the Cucumber reports which are recommended.